# How to Display a Asynchronous JSON data in a Table layout? Android parsing from a URL

Tags: android, json, listview, url

I followed [this](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-parsing-yql-using-json-tutorial/) article to Display a JSSON data forma a Url in that i am parsed my entire data and i can able to view the data

This is my data i am getting this data form a URL

```
{
"return": "success",
"Data": {
    "results": [
        {
            "viewlist": [
                {
                    "viewoffers": [],
                    "offers_count": 0,
                    "url": "N/A"
                },
                {
                    "viewoffers": [
                        {
                            "book": "java",
                            "price": "313.56"
                        },
                        {
                            "book": "java",
                            "price": "311.95"
                        }
                    ],
                    "offers_count": 2,
                    "url": "http://www.amazon.com"
                },
                {
                    "viewoffers": [
                        {
                            "book": "android",
                            "price": "339.99"
                        },
                        {
                            "book": "android",
                            "shipping": "8.17",
                            "price": "299.99"
                        }
                    ],
                    "offers_count": 2,
                    "name": "tigerdirect.com",
                    "recentoffers_count": 1,
                    "sku": "8567757",
                    "url": "http://www.ebay.com"
                }
            ],
            "model": "N/A",
            "weight": "394625.36",
            "price_currency": "USD"
        }
    ],
    "total_results_count": 1,
    "results_count": 1,
    "code": "OK",
    "offset": 0
}
}
```

So here i am Parsing and getting the data

```
JSONObject json_Data = json_data.getJSONObject("Data");
JSONArray json_results = json_Data.getJSONArray("results");
for  (int i = 0; i < json_results.length(); i++) {
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
JSONObject c = json_results.getJSONObject(i);

 JSONArray json_results_viewlist =c.getJSONArray("viewlist");
 System.out.println("looping json_results_viewlist");
 for (int j = 0; j < c.length(); j++) {
  System.out.println("looping json_results_viewlist[" + j +"]" +                 "json_results_viewlist.length() -->" + json_results_viewlist.length());
  if (j < json_results_viewlist.length()) {
  JSONObject sd = json_results_viewlist.getJSONObject(j);
  map.put("offers_count", sd.optString("offers_count"));
  map.put("url", sd.optString("url"));
  long lOffer_Counts =-1;
  try {
  lOffer_Counts= Long.parseLong(sd.optString("offers_count"));
  } catch(Exception e) {
  lOffer_Counts =-1;
  }                             

 if(lOffer_Counts > 0) {

 System.out.println(json_viewoffers.toString());
 JSONArray json_viewoffers = sd.getJSONArray("viewoffers");

  for (int k = 0; k < json_viewoffers.length(); k++) {
  HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
  JSONObject e = json_viewoffers.getJSONObject(k);
  map.put("price", e.optString("price"));
  map.put("book", e.optString("book"));

   }  
  arraylist.add(map);
```

But I want the output should be like this

[image]

and at here i am using first list-view and then second i am using a Table layout i am getting the data to the table layout with a loop but that loop is overwriting..

So i want that Loop should be incremented i can't change the server side

Comment: The best way is to use ListView.

Comment: What you have done uptill now ? Show what you have tried and ask about the issue your facing. Not to tell someone to do your job.

Comment: My Issue is that the books,price and url are overwriting i want to place them in one by one order.. Just like that list-view.

Comment: Hey user2967727 when you made some mistake every one will tech you a class But when you are right no one cares.. so don't worry Your problem is that Your loop is overwriting.. so if please increment it.

Comment: thanks you user3073115.. But when i increment that loop at the main list view i am getting only one data my list-view is collapsed.. i need to learn it how to complete,. so please any one give me any sugession..